# Is it possible to know the Rule ID's of core Fortify rules?

Tags: fortify

I'm trying to suppress some core Fortify rules as they're false positives for our organization. However, I can't seem to find a way to know their Rule ID's, which are required for the SuppressionRule tag. I checked in the Details tab of Audit Workbench but only the Instance ID is indicated there, which apparently is not the Rule ID.

If it's not really possible, how can I achieve the same feat using FilterSet instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fortify rule IDs appear in the Fortify Software Security Center at the very bottom of the details tab in the issue list.

[image]

As noted by NDAclan these IDs appear in the Analysis Information tab in the Audit Workbench.

[image]

Comment: how can I do this without this UI. I just have command lint tools.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately found it in the Analysis Evidence tab!